# upgrading form hibernate3 to hibernate 4.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Can any help how to change the parameters for the hibernate 4.2 as I am getting the following error

```
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>


   User user2 = new User();
   user2.setUserName(testDO.getUserName());
    user2.setRegisterCode(code);
    user2.setLastUpdateOn(DateUtil.getCurrentDate());
    testDAO.saveOrUpdateObject(user2);
```

*Error:*

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write
>   operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn
>   your Sessionnto FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove
>   'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.    at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1128)

Comment: could you please share code which lead to problem?

Comment: You are using the filter for Hibernate3 with hibernate4. Use the correct one.

Comment: Don't add code as comments, improve the original question instead.

Comment: Looks like you are only updating the dependencies and not the spring configuration or at least not completely.